# addClass until keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a css class (e.g. "`active`") to `#plane` until keyCode 32 (spacebar) is down (on keyUp I want to remove it).
I guess cannot use the same logic of the movement, in this case I cannot see where should I remove the class.

http://jsfiddle.net/fbFuW/220/

```js
setInterval(movePlane, 20);
var keys = {}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
});


function movePlane() {
    for (var key in keys) {
        if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
        if (key == 37) {
            $("#plane").animate({left: "-=5"}, 0);                
        }
        if (key == 38) {
            $("#plane").animate({top: "-=5"}, 0);  
        }
        if (key == 39) {
            $("#plane").animate({left: "+=5"}, 0);  
        }
        if (key == 40) {
            $("#plane").animate({top: "+=5"}, 0);  
        }
        if (key == 32) {
            $("#plane").addClass("active"); //where I should remove the class?
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body{
background:white;
}
#plane {
    height: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:40%;
}
.active {
    border:10px solid red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="plane" src='http://i.imgur.com/WmhK6mX.png' border='0'/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put keys into a structure that lets you look up whether a given key is pressed, you don’t loop over it. Equivalent to what you have now:

```
function movePlane() {
    if (keys[37]) {
        $("#plane").animate({left: "-=5"}, 0);                
    }
    if (keys[38]) {
        $("#plane").animate({top: "-=5"}, 0);  
    }
    if (keys[39]) {
        $("#plane").animate({left: "+=5"}, 0);  
    }
    if (keys[40]) {
        $("#plane").animate({top: "+=5"}, 0);  
    }
    if (keys[32]) {
        $("#plane").addClass("active");
    }
}
```

and then, to set the class according to the key:

```
$("#plane").toggleClass("active", !!keys[32]);
```

Can also use `.css()` here instead of duration-0 animations, and avoid selecting the element every time `movePlane()` is called:

```
var $plane = $("#plane");

function movePlane() {
    if (keys[37]) {
        $plane.css({left: "-=5"});                
    }
    if (keys[38]) {
        $plane.css({top: "-=5"});  
    }
    if (keys[39]) {
        $plane.css({left: "+=5"});  
    }
    if (keys[40]) {
        $plane.css({top: "+=5"});  
    }

    $plane.toggleClass("active", !!keys[32]);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I tried to put `$("#plane").toggleClass("active", !!keys[32]);`  on `$(document).keyup` callback, it doesn't work, where should I place it? Please note: I want to keep the class "active" while I'm pressing the spacebar

Comment: @alfredopacino: You replace `if (keys[32]) { $("#plane").addClass("active"); }` in `movePlane()` with it, as seen in the last code snippet. `keydown` and `keyup` don’t need to change.